# Docker: Container running in a certain port?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to use `docker ps` for a certain port. I am assuming at any given time there would be only one container running on a certain port.

What if I want to get the output of `docker ps` on a particular port number say 1433?

Comment: If you are running on bash `docker ps | grep 1433`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see the port that is mapped to into the container, you can try:

```
docker ps --filter "expose=80"
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering) there is no supported built-in filter by port, so you will have to filter the output using [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (or [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490907(v=technet.10)) if you are on a Windows machine)